# Oracle database - link to MySql on Mac?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, linker, odbc

I'm working with a remote Oracle database and would like to create a link to a local MySQL database on my Macbook Pro.  From what I've read it sounds possible, but I'm not sure how to get things setup.

I believe I need ODBC connection info setup on my Mac in the odbc.ini file.  I can't find where that file should be, or what info to enter into it.  I've come across Mac app "ODBC Manager" which looks like it should help with setup, but I see no instructions on how to use it.  Can ODBC connection info be setup through other clients like Sequel Pro or SQL Developer?

I'm currently running Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite).  I could update to Sierra if that would make the odbc setup/linking easier.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to upgrade OS X, in any case.

Are you trying to make MySQL consume data from Oracle?  I do not believe this is possible.

Or make Oracle consume data from MySQL?  This is done with DG4ODBC, an Oracle helper application, as **[Oracle -> DG4ODBC -> ODBC driver for MySQL -> MySQL](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/dataspace/owiki/wiki/UdaWikiWeb/ConfigHSODBCr9)**.

DG4ODBC is available for various platforms (which do not include OS X).  You'll need an ODBC driver for MySQL (such as [those from my employer](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-mysql/)) installed on the same platform; DG4ODBC will need to be TCP/IP accessible by Oracle from its host; and MySQL on your Mac will need to be TCP/IP accessible by DG4ODBC from its host.

Comment: Right, I'm trying to get Oracle to consume data from MySQL.

Comment: However, I don't have admin privileges on the Oracle side, so can't install additional software.  Seems like that's required for this solution to work, yes?

Comment: You don't need to install additional software on the Oracle host. You do need a DG4ODBC-supported environment (like Linux, which may be on a VM, which may be on your Mac, if the VM gets its own IP address). Three (physical or virtual) machines -- Oracle host; DG4ODBC host with ODBC Driver for MySQL; MySQL host. You *do* need the ability to tweak some configuration files on the Oracle host. See [the article I linked above](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/dataspace/owiki/wiki/UdaWikiWeb/ConfigHSODBCr9).

Comment: Ok thanks.  I don't have access to update settings/config files on the host Oracle system though.

Comment: Then I am afraid you cannot make a live link. The best that can be done is data replication between MySQL and Oracle, using a distinct tool which connects to both DBMS as a client of each. [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), from [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/) (my employer), can perform such replication, whether snapshot or transactional, [programmatically](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/ch-repl/) or through the [Conductor, Virtuoso's browser-based admin interface](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/replicationandsynchronization/).